# Selenium Python randomly failed about stale element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I write the robot for automation testing by reading the input from excel and calling the python method for doing a step. In python, I use xpath to find the /td of text. This is my script,

```
def accounts_populate_filtros(self, str_name, bln_edit = False):
   path = ("(//* [contains(text(),'%s')]/ancestor::table[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_tcUser_tpFilter_cblScopeFilters']/descendant::input/..)"% str(str_name))
   selected_element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, path)))
   WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, path)))
   self.accounts_list_checkbox_select(selected_element, bln_edit)
```

At the parameter, the robot reads the excel file and passes the text that want to find for variable 'str_name'. After this function, it calls 'accounts_list_checkbox_select' to find own checkbox and tick, this function is working fine.

Here is the web code that I want to test. This one, the text that I want to refer is 'Branch TH1'.

```html
By using our site, you acknowledge that you have read and understand our Cookie Policy, Privacy Policy, and our Terms of Service.

<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_tcUser_tpFilter" class="ajax__tab_panel" style="visibility: visible;">
            
                                                        <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_tcUser_tpFilter_upEditViewFilters">
                
                                                                <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_tcUser_tpFilter_pFilterTabContent" style="height:350px;width:570px;">
                    
                                                                    <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_tcUser_tpFilter_pScopesControl">
                        
                                                                        <table style="width: 500px">
                                                                            <tbody><tr>
                                                                                <td align="right">
                                                                                    <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_tcUser_tpFilter_lblApplication">Aplicación:</span>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                <td align="left">
                                                                                    <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$tcUser$tpFilter$ddlApplication" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$tcUser$tpFilter$ddlApplication\',\'\')', 0)" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_tcUser_tpFilter_ddlApplication">
                            <option selected="selected" value="2">Aplicacion caja registradora.</option>
                            <option value="4">Aplicacion de Dashboard para Transactional Switch</option>
                            <option value="3">Aplicacion de partner portal.</option>
                            <option value="6">Aplicacion Prueba Symetric</option>
                            <option value="1">Aplicacion web central.</option>
                            <option value="5">Aplicación WebTeller</option>

                        </select>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td align="right">
                                                                                    <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_tcUser_tpFilter_lblScope">Alcance:</span>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                <td align="left">
                                                                                    <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_tcUser_tpFilter_upEditViewFiltersScopes">
                            
                                                                                            <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$tcUser$tpFilter$ddlScope" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$tcUser$tpFilter$ddlScope\',\'\')', 0)" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_tcUser_tpFilter_ddlScope">
                                <option value="6">Instancia de Aplicación</option>
                                <option selected="selected" value="4">Agencia</option>
                                <option value="5">Caja</option>
                                <option value="3">Cadena</option>
                                <option value="1">Operación</option>
                                <option value="2">Proveedor</option>
                                <option value="7">DES scope de prueba 2</option>

                            </select>
                                                                                        
                        </div>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </tbody></table>
                                                                    
                    </div>
                                                                    <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_tcUser_tpFilter_pScopesChecks" style="text-align:left;">
                        
                                                                        <table border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; height: 25px; width: 100%;">
                                                                            <tbody><tr>
                                                                                <td align="left">
                                                                                    <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_tcUser_tpFilter_upEditViewFiltersFilterEnabledControls">
                            
                                                                                            <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_tcUser_tpFilter_rbScopeFilterEnabled" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$tcUser$tpFilter$rbScopeFilterStatus" value="rbScopeFilterEnabled" checked="checked"><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_tcUser_tpFilter_rbScopeFilterEnabled">Habilitar</label>
                                                                                            <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_tcUser_tpFilter_rbScopeFilterDisabled" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$tcUser$tpFilter$rbScopeFilterStatus" value="rbScopeFilterDisabled" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$tcUser$tpFilter$rbScopeFilterDisabled\',\'\')', 0)"><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_tcUser_tpFilter_rbScopeFilterDisabled">Inhabilitar</label>
                                                                                        
                        </div>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                <td align="right">
                                                                                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$tcUser$tpFilter$txtScopeSearch" type="text" id="txtScopeSearch" maxlength="50" style="width: 200px;" onkeyup="window.ManageUser.EditView.eventHandlers.txtScopeSearch_OnKeyPress(this, event)" onkeydown="window.ManageUser.EditView.eventHandlers.txtScopeSearch_OnKeyPress(this, event)" value="Branch TH1">
                                                                                    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$tcUser$tpFilter$btnScopeSearch" value="Buscar" id="btnScopeSearch" style="width:60px;">
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </tbody></table>
                                                                        <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_tcUser_tpFilter_upEditViewFiltersFilterList">
                            
                                                                                <table border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; height: 310px; width: 100%;">
                                                                                    <tbody><tr>
                                                                                        <td colspan="2">
                                                                                            <div style="height: 285px; overflow-y: scroll;">
                                                                                                <table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_tcUser_tpFilter_cblScopeFilters" style="font-size:XX-Small;">
                                <tbody><tr>
                                    <td><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_tcUser_tpFilter_cblScopeFilters_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$tcUser$tpFilter$cblScopeFilters$0" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$tcUser$tpFilter$cblScopeFilters$0\',\'\')', 0)" value="8121"><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_tcUser_tpFilter_cblScopeFilters_0">Branch TH1</label></td><td></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody></table>
                                                                                            </div>
                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                    <tr style="height: 24px;">
                                                                                        <td colspan="2">
                                                                                            
<table align="center" width="350px">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td align="left" style="width: 50px;">
            <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$tcUser$tpFilter$cblScopeFiltersPager$lbtFirst" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_tcUser_tpFilter_cblScopeFiltersPager_lbtFirst" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled" src="../Images/first2.png">
        </td>
        <td align="left" style="width: 50px;">
            <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$tcUser$tpFilter$cblScopeFiltersPager$lbtPrevious" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_tcUser_tpFilter_cblScopeFiltersPager_lbtPrevious" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled" src="../Images/previous2.png">
        </td>
        <td align="center" style="width: 150px;">
            <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_tcUser_tpFilter_cblScopeFiltersPager_lblPageCounter">Page 1/1</span>
        </td>
        <td align="right" style="width: 50px;">
            <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$tcUser$tpFilter$cblScopeFiltersPager$lbtNext" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_tcUser_tpFilter_cblScopeFiltersPager_lbtNext" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled" src="../Images/next2.png">
        </td>
        <td align="right" style="width: 50px;">
            <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$tcUser$tpFilter$cblScopeFiltersPager$lbtLast" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_tcUser_tpFilter_cblScopeFiltersPager_lbtLast" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled" src="../Images/last2.png">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                </tbody></table>
                                                                            
                        </div>
                                                                    
                    </div>
                                                                
                </div>
                                                            
            </div>
                                                    
        </div>
```

There are actually many input at a time, so this function will be picked to run for many times per a robot running following the input from excel. But when I run, I found that it randomly failed at the this line,

```
selected_element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, path)))
```

The error shows as here,

```
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

I don't think the xpath is wrong, because as I told, it randomly failed and passed. Each time running, it always failed at this line of code but different input. Sometime, some input runs pass, but at the different time running, that input runs fail with the error above. It wired. Please help.

Comment: check if element exist in doom in each loop. Try to add `time.sleep(2)`.

Comment: I did try time.sleep(2), also 5, 10 :(.
Anyway, I think I found it's not because of script. It might be causing from server or something of web. Because when I run it today, it happens less than yesterday. Yesterday I found it failed 7 out of 10 times, but today it's only 1 out of 10 times with the same script (without time.sleep), nothing changes, Wiredo.